# Variable doesn’t change when I pass it to a function and modify it inside

Tags: javascript, pass-by-reference

I want the `check` function to prepend `"0"` to `hour` if it is below `10`.

```js
var date = new Date();
var day = date.getDate();
var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
var year = date.getFullYear();
var hour = date.getHours();
var minutes = date.getMinutes();

function check(x) {
  if (x < 10) {
    x = '0' + x;
  }
};
check(hour);
console.log(hour);
```

But when I check `console.log(hour);` it still returns the previous value. Why is this the case?

Comment: `return "0" + x;` and `return x;` outside the `if`; then `hour = check(hour)`. Assignment is useless. You could also simply use `var hour = String(date.getHours()).padStart(2, "0");`.

Comment: Use ```hour = '0' + x``` instead of ```x = '0' + x``` ..

Comment: The `x` you assign inside the function is another variable which is not related to the global variable `x` in any way.

Comment: I think to understand it you must investigate the concepts of passing a parameter "by value" or "by reference". It happens because, when you are passing `hour` as parameter, you are actually only passing a copy of the value `hour` has, not its memory address itself (that would be passing "by reference"). That is why despite you change `hour`value inside the function, it doesn´t affect outside the function, because inside the function you were only using `hour` value but not making a real assignment to its memory address. https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-pass-by-value/

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the value and you need to take the value from the function for an output or assignment.

```
function check(x) {
    if (x < 10) {
        return '0' + x;
    }
    return x;
}
```

In this case, I would change the name of the function to `getFormatted` and uzse a more abstract approach.

```js
function getFormatted(value, size = 2) {
    return value.toString().padStart(size, 0);
}

var date = new Date();
var day = date.getDate();
var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
var year = date.getFullYear();
var hour = date.getHours();
var minutes = date.getMinutes();

console.log(getFormatted(hour));
```

Comment: I figured it out in another way.
As I can see there is no way to add hour new value inside a function. So i did it like that:
```
hour = check(hour);
```
and  it works! :)

THANKS everyone for your effort
THANKS